# executing java command from VBA on MAC

Tags: java, macos, vba

I would simply like to execute a java class from within VBA on MAC.

In the MAC terminal one just types `"java"` and it executes the java command.

I tried:

```
t = "Macintosh HD:System:Library:Java:JavaVirtualMachines:1.6.0.jdk:Contents:Home:bin:java"
MacScript (t)
```

or

```
   t = "Macintosh HD:System:Library:Java:JavaVirtualMachines:1.6.0.jdk:Contents:Home:bin:java"
   shell (t)
```

but get `runtime error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument.`

I guess this is because 1.6.0.jdk is not simply a folder which I can include in the path - but I am not sure.

How would I have to call java from within VBA?

once this works I need to actually call: `java myFile`

How do I include the complete path for the java command and then the complete path for myFile?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a Java function from VBA unless you use a run time bridge like this [JavaBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/) or you can use Web Services to wrap your VBA.

Comment: so what you are saying is that one cannot just emulate/simulate the same commands with VBA shell command that one can type in the terminal - really disapointing.. Would it be possible by simulating the keystrokes that starts the terminal and types in the command then at least?

Comment: that's sad - on PC it was really easy, just call a *.bat file that's it.

Comment: That's not sad, its what you get when you use MS. It only works there and nowhere else. BTW, you did not just call a .bat file on a PC. It already has all the bridge libraries and dll's installed. You're doing the same thing as my answer, its just that you're doing it.

Comment: I just read something about .command files on the MAC - so that won't work without having to manually install bridges on the MAC? I was abot to try it, but I really don't want to spend too much time on installing extra stuff on the MAC...